# Set file privileges in navigational menu with php

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

Hello and thanks for the help in advance. I have a more robust version of this that i am working on but I need something for the short term. We created a 2 tier user access to an administrative panel. Employee and Administrators. The code below is a short version example of the longer version we are implementing in the short term. First I want to check their access level if it is level 1 or level 0. This is a method in OOP.

```
    function menuPriviledge($dbCon){

        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

        if($accessLevel = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT access FROM UserProfiles WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 0, 1")){
            while($accessData = $accessLevel->fetch_assoc()){
                $access = $accessData['access'];
            }
        }
```

After i get done echoing this top portion i am getting the correct answer, I am getting an access level 1 associated with the current username in the account. That is what I was looking for so we're good but then on the next if statement i test that the variable $access is = to 1 (Statement below) if it is equal to 1 I call on printf and display a present list of nav menus prepared for administrators else a different preset menu for employees with limited page access is displayed.

```
            if(isset($access)){

                switch($access){

                case 1: 
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM CVCUserFilePrivileges";
                    if($files = $this->dbConnection->query($query)){
                        while($access = $files->fetch_assoc()){
                            printf("<li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Directory Listings</a></li>
                                <li><a title=\"Ads Manager\"><i class=\"icon-laptop\"></i>Ads Manager<span>5</span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Dealer Paid Listings</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Listing Side Ads</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Scrap Metal Page Ads</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Coin Request Page Ads</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Dealer Form Page Ads</a></li>
                                    </ul>                   
                                </li>", $access['directoryList'], $access['dlrPaidListing'], $access['listingSideAds'], $access['scrapMetalAds'], $access['coinRequestAds'], $access['dlrFormAds']);
                        }
                    }
                break;
                case 0:
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM CVCUserFilePrivileges";
                    if($files = $this->dbConnection->query($query)){
                        while($access = $files->fetch_assoc()){
                            printf("<li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Directory Listings</a></li>
                                <li><a title=\"Ads Manager\"><i class=\"icon-laptop\"></i>Ads Manager<span>1</span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href=\"%s\"><i class=\"icon-angle-right\"></i>Dealer Paid Listings</a></li>
                                    </ul>                   
                                </li>", $access['directory'], $access['dlrPaidListing']);
                        }
                    }
                break;
                default:
                    echo "There is an error, no access level set, contact your database administrator";
                }
            }
```

When it semi works, it continues to add the first page link to every single nav option underneath it, so every nav option leads to the same page. When it doesn't work it just completely disappears and the nav doesn't even exist. I hope I was able to explain this well enough. The problem seems to be on the if statement where I test their level of access, before displaying the nav menu.

Comment: Hi @RookieRecruits ... First: For good practices you have to initiate the `$access` variable before your `if` statement. Second: If your user have only two types of access, you don't need to use `else if`. Only `else` tag. Third: Your SQL queries are the same in both cases **Administrator** and **Employees**.

Comment: Thank you @ThiagoAugustusOliveira I will try it with without the elseif, The sql queries are the same because amount of files available to each access level has already been predetermined and hard coded into the php. Above I only show 1 <li> tag but in the actual version they will have a different amounts of pages in the nav. This will buy me time.

Comment: Did you get any progress?

Comment: no still trying to work it out. @ThiagoAugustusOliveira hoping to get this done today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
if(isset($access)) {

    switch($access) {

        case 1:
           // do the code
           break;

        case 2:
           // do the code
           break;

    }
}else{
    echo "access not set";
}
```

Try this.

Ps.: 1 its different from "1". Did you put your sql field as int?

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira I changed the statement to a switch statement and it is just not working at the moment. Tried this but I am still getting a blank menu. It is just not appearing. I changed the database to make the access column INT and used 1 instead of  '1' everything else works fine except when it gets to the switch statement. is there a way to post it in this so you can see the updates? thank you both for your help.

Comment: Let's try to debug that. Comment the switch statement and put `echo $access;` See what's the output and tell me, please.

Comment: I did that earlier and it gave me a 1 which is correct. I just double checked it. Earlier I also took away the printf(" "); turned into and echo and changed the the data at the end to the inside of the menu to see if that worked but still received an empty response. No menu appeared.

Comment: I noticed that when I take out the while statement it shows but only the first link in the list is attached to every nav tab so you can only go to one page.

Comment: Ok, so try something. Put some html code in another file and after the `case 1:` put an include and get this html you just created. Do the same thing on the `case 0:` but with a different html. See what happens.

Comment: Hey it worked! Thank you! I did the include(); and now it alternates between the 2 levels of admin access however, the menus were dependent on a SESSION[] global var that once implemented it tested for username and the access level associated to that username. Once the global variable was inserted all of the pages began acting exactly the way I needed them to. Awesome suggestions and thank you for your help.

Comment: Also the php became lighter with the syntax you provided so it loads a lot faster. Part of me doesn't want to make it more complicated since the company will not need a robust menu selection like some fortune 500 companies have.

Comment: Oh, glad to help! Yeah, with that syntax it becomes more easy to read and to run. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work fully while protecting the pages I added this simple code to store the current username that logged in during the login process

```
        session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
```

Then I added an include file that contains something like the below syntax.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $userId = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo "You don't have credentials to enter...";
    exit();
    die();
}
```

This include was added to all of the files or I also had the option to include the common include files that go in all pages into an include file that will carry all of the common include(); files. Now it restricts access unless someone logs in but if anyone has a better way of optimizing this code let me know. I thought this version was simple and light. Any additional levels of security that anyone can recommend please feel free to let me know. Someone else can probably use this too.

Now based on the username stored in `$userId` it will provide the correct menu.

The syntax for the menu was something like what's below.

```
class menu{

    public function __construct($dbCon){
        $this->dbConn = $dbCon;
    }

    function menuPriviledges($dbCon){

        global $userId;

            if($accessLev = $this->dbConn->query("SELECT access FROM UserProfiles WHERE userId = '$userId'")){
                while($Data = $accessLev->fetch_assoc()){
                    $access = $Data['access'];
                }
            }

            if($access == 1){
                include('common-menu-admin.php');
            } elseif($access == 0) {
                include('common-menu-employee.php');
            }

    }
}
```

Now it all works and is fast too!